how do i edit a static readonly integer? (harmony/reflection)
there's a specific variable that i need to edit, it's not accessible through an actual instance of the class because it's static and whatever i've tried either didnt work or nulled
i've tried to use reflection
both field.SetValue(Type.instance, 26) nulled and field.SetValue(null, 26) nulled(because that's what i could find for static variables)
with harmony traverse it just doesnt change the variable
I've tried going over other posts about the same issue but none of them worked here
for the integer to go from 25 to 26 (base value is 25, 26 is just a test number and will be most likely changed later)

Please edit the question to include a [mre].

For a private static field, you'd need NonPublic and Static binding flags.
using System.Reflection;
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetType("Test")
    .GetField("thing", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
    .SetValue(null, 26);

Test.Write();

public class Test
{
    private static int thing = 0;

    public static void Write()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(thing);
    }
}

If you're using an already loaded (into your process) assembly, something like this may be what you need:
Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Test))
    .GetType("SomeNamespace.Test")
    .GetField("thing", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
    .SetValue(null, 26);

If you haven't loaded the assembly, you can:
Assembly.Load("SomeAssembly")
    .GetType("SomeNamespace.Test")
    .GetField("thing", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
    .SetValue(null, 26);


im trying to access a variable from a completely different namespace/dll/reference (i dont know the term for it), also this just null error object is not set to an instance of an object errors

@elmish Edit you question to include what you tried, including the code and any additional details.  Since you already have a Type object, remove Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("blah") from your code, its likely throwing null on the GetType bcz its not in the executing assembly..

eh doesnt matter, turns out the value can never be changed and is there just cause
it didnt limit what i needed anyways
thanks for trying
